# Insert and retrieve Image from Mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm new to php.
I want to add images into Database and display every image when new image is uploaded.
Every image is getting inserted into database.
My problem is only first image is getting retrieved but i want to display all images from database.This is my code

```
<?php
    ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);
    ini_set('default_socket_time',300);

?>


<html>
<body>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <br>
        <input type="file" name="image">
        <br><br>    
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload">

    </form>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])==FALSE)
            {
                echo "Please select an image.";
            }
            else{
                $image=addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                $name=addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
                $image=file_get_contents($image);
                $image=base64_encode($image);
                saveimage($name,$image);
            }
        }
        displayimage();
        function saveimage($name,$image)
        {
            $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            mysql_select_db("sanket",$con);
            $qry="insert into images (name,image) value ('$name','$image')";
            $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
            if($result)
            {
                //echo "<br>Image uploaded.";
            }
            else
            {
                //echo "<br>Image not uploaded";
            }
        }
        function displayimage()
        {
            $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            mysql_select_db("sanket",$con);
            $qry="select * from images";
            $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row['image'].'"'; 
            }
            mysql_close($con);
        }
    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bad start!, do not use deprecated function, try MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Have you tried looking in your database directly to check that there is actually more than one entry in the table?

Comment: @Lynch Yeah every time i upload new image its getting uploaded.And its showing in the database too.

Comment: Upload images to a file system and leave a file ref only in the data base

Comment: @FintanCreaven: Seriously i Don't know how to do that :(

Comment: Look up uploading files via PHP on google many of these will also show you how to display them as well. You get a good choice of tutorials. With the database you can just store the file path and not the image.

Comment: @FintanCreaven: Thanks a lot.I will search for it and surely implement this in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didnt close the image tag. use  it like this

```
echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row['image'].'" />';
```

Comment: Thank you..Thank you so much..:)

Comment: Yes it did..U solved my problem dude..Now my work has become much more simpler..Thanks once again

Comment: @jackkds7: As a general rule, looking at the generated HTML in your browser page source and debugging tools will help you identify these errors *very* easily.